# Swagger required parameter returns 500 when missing instead of 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, swagger

I have a REST endpoint that has a request parameter “myParam”.  This is a required parameter without which any GET request made to this endpoint is considered a bad request.  I’m using Swagger to highlight the fact that this parameter is required, as follows

```
@ApiParam(required = true) @RequestParam(value = "myParam") String myParam
```

The problem is that when I submit a GET to this endpoint via Postman the HTTP error returned is a 500 saying that the required parameter myParam is not provided.  Is there any way to refactor this so that if a parameter labelled by Swagger as required is missing the response is 404 instead?

Comment: Can you update the question with the GET request you are sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be creating a class and annotate it with `@ControllerAdvice`. This class' methods are responsible for handling specific exception passed as parameters. In your `500` error there should be an exception stack trace like *"Caused by .. org.somepackage.SomeException ..."*.

1) You can create a custom class which contains a message and a HttpStatus code:

```
public class ExceptionResponse {
  private HttpStatus httpStatus;
  private String errorMessage;
  //getters;setters;
}
```

2) The `@ControllerAdvice` annotated class should look like this :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestExceptionHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(value = SomeException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ExceptionResponse> handleMissingRequiredParameters(SomeException ex) {
    ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse();
    exceptionResponse.setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    exceptionResponse.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(exceptionResponse, exceptionResponse.getHttpStatus());
}
}
```

And now, when the `SomeException` is thrown, the actual response that you'll see is an `ExceptionResponse` JSON with a custom `httpStatus` and `errorMessage`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give that a try