# How to respond with code 401 or 404 instead of 500 in go-swagger for invalid bearer token

Tags: go, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen, go-swagger

I have created a REST API server using go-swagger and added bearer token security to a few endpoints. As per docs, the token verification method should have a signature like `func(string) (interface{}, error)`.

The token verification method returns an error if the passed bearer token is not valid. This results in 500 responses to the requestor with JSON response body:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Token is expired"
}
```

However, as standers how can I make this response with code 401.

**Note**: A similar discussion like this for Java can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/60738107/16087692 , Is there any way to achieve this Go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no experience with go-swagger but just stumbled upon this question.
The answer is in the examples:
https://github.com/go-swagger/go-swagger/tree/master/examples/authentication

The example shows that the function returns an:

```
errors.New(401, "incorrect api key auth")
```

This is an error from the package: "github.com/go-openapi/errors" where you can pass in a http status code.

Comment: It worked for me, Thank you @Jørgen